Handling Multiple Targets in CocoaPods Causes libPods to Link Only One Target Instead of All Targets
I'm managing two targets in my React Native iOS Project and I tried to manage in the Podfile. Later after doing pod install, in Xcode's Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries, only the Dev target have its libPods linked, namely with libPods-MyApp (Dev).a. When i clicked "reveal in project navigator", in the Frameworks folder it only shows libPods-MyApp (Dev).a and libPods-MyAppTests.a whereas the libPods-MyApp.a or just libPods.a are missing, and it causes build errors on my main target.
My Podfile are shown below:
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '8.15.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.0'

pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '3.9.0'
# pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

# Define find-and-replace function
def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      replaced = text.index(replacestr)
      if replaced == nil && text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end

def shared_pods
  # rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  # pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  # pod 'react-native-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'RNFBApp', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app'
  pod 'RNFBMessaging', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging'
  pod 'react-native-blob-util', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-blob-util'
  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'
  # pod 'RNSentry', :path => '../node_modules/@sentry/react-native/RNSentry.podspec'

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
  inherit! :complete
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'MyApp' do
  shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp (Dev)' do
  shared_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
  react_native_post_install(installer)

  # To build for the simulator on Apple M1
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # This will apply these settings on every Pod
      # disables arm64 builds for the simulator
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end

  # Fix for XCode 12.5 & RN 0.64.X - See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28405
  find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/React/CxxBridge/RCTCxxBridge.mm",
  "_initializeModules:(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)modules", "_initializeModules:(NSArray<Class> *)modules")

  find_and_replace("../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm",
    "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(strongModule))", "RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass(Class(strongModule)))")

  # Fix for Flipper-Folly on iOS 14.5
  find_and_replace("Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
    "atomic_notify_one(state)", "folly::atomic_notify_one(state)")

  find_and_replace("Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
    "atomic_notify_one(state)", "folly::atomic_notify_one(state)")

  find_and_replace("Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
    "atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)", "folly::atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)")
end

I expected that libPods-MyApp.a or libPods.a to be present, but currently it only creates libPods-MyApp (Dev).a and libPods-MyAppTests.a.
I'm pretty sure there's something wrong in my Podfile but i don't know what is it, so please help me on pointing out what went wrong in my Podfile config. Thank you.
